Let $b=\sqrt[3] 2$, $c=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt {-3}}{2}$ with $a=bc$. Prove $b+a$ and $b-a$ has degree $3$ and $6$ over $\mathbb Q$, respectively.
Let $b=\sqrt[3] 2$, $c=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt {-3}}{2}$ with $a=bc$ in $\mathbb C$. Prove that $b+a$ and $b-a$ has degree $3$ and $6$ over $\mathbb Q$, respectively.
My attempts: $b+a=b+bc=b(1+c)=\sqrt[3] 2\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt {3}}{2}i\right)$.
Let $2X=\sqrt[3] 2+\sqrt[3] 2\sqrt 2 i \implies (2X-\sqrt[3] 2)^3=-6\sqrt 3$ however left part will not be a polynomial over $\mathbb Q$ as it consists of $\sqrt[3] 2$ and $\sqrt[3] 4$.
Similarly for $b-a=b-bc=b(1-c)=\sqrt[3] 2\left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{\sqrt {3}}{2}i\right)$.
Let $2x=3\sqrt[3] 2+\sqrt[3] 2\sqrt 3 i\implies (2x-3\sqrt[3] 2)^3=-6\sqrt 3$. However I am far away to reach a polynomial of degree $6$ for the part $b.$

Try $(b+a)^3$….

If I equate $(b+a)^3$ to $X$ then $X^3= f$ where$f$ consists of the term $\sqrt 3 i/2$ which does not lie in $\mathbb Q$.

$X^3=(\sqrt[3] 2(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt {3}}{2}i))^3=2(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt {3}}{2}i)^3=2(\frac{1}{8}+\frac{\sqrt 3i}{8}- \frac{3}{2}-\frac{3\sqrt 3}{8})$

That’s not correct

$(a+b)^3=a^3+\color{red}3a^2b+\color{red}3ab^2+b^3$

Are you familiar with $e^{iz}=\cos{z}+i\sin{z}$?

$2X=\sqrt[3] 2+\sqrt[3] 2\sqrt 2 i \implies (2X-\sqrt[3] 2)^3=-\color{red}{4\sqrt 2i}$ and $2x=3\sqrt[3] 2+\sqrt[3] 2\sqrt 3 i\implies (2x-3\sqrt[3] 2)^3=-6\sqrt 3\color{red}i$

and $1-c=\frac32\color{red}-\frac{\sqrt3}2i$

Note that $c$ can be recognized as a complex cube root of unity, with $\dfrac{c^3-1}{c-1}=c^2+c+1=0$.
Then it becomes obvious that $b+a=b(1+c)=b(-c^2)$,
so $(b+a)^3=b^3(-c^6)=2(-1)=-2.$
[You should also check that
$\left(\sqrt[3]2\left(\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i\right)\right)^3=2\left(\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i\right)^3=2\left(\frac18+3\frac14\frac{\sqrt3}2i-3\frac12\frac34-\frac{3\sqrt3}8i\right)=2(-1)=-2.]$
Also, $b-a=b(1-c)=\sqrt[3]2\sqrt3\left(\frac{\sqrt3}2-\frac i2\right)$, so $(b-a)^2=\sqrt[3]4\cdot3\left(\frac12-\frac{\sqrt3}2i\right)=\sqrt[3]4\cdot3(-c),$
so $(b-a)^6=4\cdot27(-c^3)=-108.$
[Note that $\left(\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i\right)^6=1$ and $\left(\frac{\sqrt3}2-\frac i2\right)^{12}=1;$
you might be familiar with those from trigonometry.]
Does this help?
